# How set Sub captions horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I used `vspace and hspace` to align upper figures with the lowers manually, but upper sub captions do not move with  the upper sub figures. What command i must use to locate upper sub captions canter of figures like lower figures and sub captions.[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{+0.4\baselineskip}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\linewidth}
   \vspace*{-0mm}\hspace*{-7mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.eps}
    \hspace*{\fill}\caption{airfoils shape}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.34\linewidth}
   \vspace*{-0mm}\hspace*{1mm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.eps}
     \caption{Surface pressure distributions}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
   \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results Initial and Optimum airfoil results Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \label{fig7}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, you need to move the images around in order to align their axes.  Second, you need to make subfigure think they are all the same size.

The `\raisebox` command primarily moves images around by moving their baselines, but can also change their height and depth which is more useful in environments which ignore baselines (like subfigures).  The `\makebox` command can change the effective width of an image.  So between the two, you should be able to align everything.

The following is not a solution to your particular problem, not having access to your images, but an illustration of how to move images without letting LaTeX know they have been moved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\movebox}{momom}% #1 = raise distance
% #2 = effective total height (optional)
% #3 = slide distance (positive right}
% #4 = effective width (optional)
% #5 = contents
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#5}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0}{\dimen0=#2\relax}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\dimen1=\wd0}{\dimen1=#4\relax}%
  \raisebox{#1}[\dimexpr \dimen0-\dp0][\dp0]% for images \dp0=0pt
    {\makebox[\dimen1][l]{\hspace{#3}\box0}}%
\egroup}
\begin{document}
Move a box to right without letting \verb|\fbox| know it moved.

\fbox{\movebox{0pt}{2em}{\rule{1em}{1ex}}}

Move a box to left without letting \verb|\fbox| know it moved.

\fbox{\movebox{0pt}{-2em}{\rule{1em}{1ex}}}

Move a box down without letting \verb|\fbox| know it moved.

\fbox{\movebox{-\baselineskip}{0pt}{\rule{1em}{1ex}}} baseline

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
%\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.4\baselineskip}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.eps}
    \caption{airfoils shape}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.eps}
     \caption{Surface pressure distributions}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
   \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Initial and Optimum airfoil results Initial and Optimum airfoil results Initial and Optimum airfoil results}
  \label{fig7}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I made minir changes in your MWE: remove all `\vspace*`  and `\hspace*` commands, between images insert `\hfil` and insert empty line between second and third image. By this the second row of images are well defined. For more space between images I add before second row command `\medskip`.

Since I haven't your images, I use option `demo` in `\documentclass`. IN real document you need to delete it.

Also instead of `graphics` package you should load `graphicx`

Comment: @ Zarko,Thanks. Actually my purpose is aligning vertical axis (make images equal width) of two upper figures with below with `{number\linewidth}` because if different size of figures, but their captions dont move with upper figures. As can be seen from my figure (a) it is on right side and figure (b) is in left side and dong move with figures. is it possible to move sub captions with figures simultaneously?

Comment: This is possible to do if your images are drawn on the same way. For example, if they are drawn with `pgfplots` than you can ensure, that the size of images and their axis width are the same and axis are aligned. But this request is not part of your question nor you provide code for images.